# Guava's Striped Lock on 2 Collections

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, guava

I don't want to use synchronized due to performance reasons, and I need 2 multimaps from Guava.
Let's suppose we have a class that works with these 2 Maps:

```
private final Multimap<String, String> rolesByUsers = HashMultimap.create();
private final Multimap<String, String> usersByRoles = HashMultimap.create();

public Collection<String> getAllUsersByRole(String role) {

    Lock lock = stripedLock.get(role).readLock();

    try {
        lock.lock();
        return usersByRoles.get(role);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public Collection<String> getAllRolesByUser(String userId) {
    Lock lock = stripedLock.get(userId).readLock();

    try {
        lock.lock();
        return rolesByUsers.get(userId);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

The above 2 methods don't block each other.

My question is: how to properly synchronize on one of those collections inside the following method? My lock is **striped**, meaning it has a set of smaller hashed locks inside. Can I lock the whole set of keys just for reading? Any other options?

```
@Override
public Collection<String> getAllUsers() {
    return rolesByUsers.keySet();
}
```

Comment: You can lock the stripe array (see `getAt` and `size`). But your code looks broken because write operations must be guarded by an exclusive lock due to the [infinite loop problem](http://mailinator.blogspot.com/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html). Then it becomes questionable if the striping is more efficient for lookups than a single exclusive lock.

Comment: @Ben Manes That's a tricky one! Thanks for the good article. If I use an exclusive lock for the write operation, I will have to use it for reads too due to JMM happens-before rules. And yes, micro benchmarks are needed. I'll try to come up with other data structures

Comment: Sorry I poorly phrased exclusive write lock. Since you're using a striped read/write lock I was thinking of a write acquiring the full array. A read lock couldn't be acquired until the resize completes, so the JMM is satisfied. However I don't see why that would be faster than a normal lock, which has less overhead and probably isn't heavily contended.

Comment: @BenManes Sure, most likely it's not worth it to mess with lock striping in this particular case, since it's just an example. I just wanted a quick access, hence came up with multi maps off the top of my head.